# STOMP sockJS and ActiveMQ over Jetty server

Tags: java, jetty, activemq-classic, stomp, sockjs

I'm trying to use STOMP with SockJS and ActiveMQ over Jetty Server in `karaf` `osgi` framework. I am able to run WebSocket on embedded Tomcat server but issue while using with Jetty server. My karaf is internally using Jetty server.

```
 transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient())); // Got error for this in jetty
```

So changed `StandardWebSocketClient` to `JettyWebSocketClient`

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    StompSession session = createStompWSConnection(WEBSOCKET_URI, new MyStompSessionHandler());
    System.out.println("Session = " + session.getSessionId());
}  

public static StompSession createStompWSConnection(String socketURL,StompSessionHandler sessionHandler) throws Exception {
    List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<Transport>();

    //transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient())); 
    transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new JettyWebSocketClient()));

    SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
    //stompClient.setMessageConverter(new Mapp);

    StompSession session = stompClient.connect(socketURL,sessionHandler).get(); //error occurs here
    System.out.println("Session : " + session);
    session.subscribe("/queue/msg",  sessionHandler);
    return session;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.ClientEndpointConfig$Configurator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

**EDIT 2 -**

Added Jetty Websocket client dependency now I'm getting this error -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
<artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
<version>9.3.2.v20150730</version>
</dependency>
```

Exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebSocketClient@2092066706 is not started
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture.get(SettableListenableFuture.java:122)
    at com.spring.jms.sockJS.App.createStompWSConnection(App.java:44)
    at com.spring.jms.sockJS.App.main(App.java:27)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was while connecting to `stompClient.connect(socketURL,sessionHandler).get();` I also added comments where the error actually occurred. I resolved the issue by replacing `transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new JettyWebSocketClient()));` to `transports.add(new RestTemplateXhrTransport());`

Here are the changes :

```
public static StompSession createStompWSConnection(String socketURL,StompSessionHandler sessionHandler) throws Exception {
    List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<Transport>();

    //transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient())); 
    //transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new JettyWebSocketClient()));
    transports.add(new RestTemplateXhrTransport());
    SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
    //stompClient.setMessageConverter(new Mapp);

    StompSession session = stompClient.connect(socketURL,sessionHandler).get(); //error occurs here
    System.out.println("Session : " + session);
    session.subscribe("/queue/msg",  sessionHandler);
    return session;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The exception indicates what the problem is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.ClientEndpointConfig$Configurator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

The class `javax.websocket.ClientEndpointConfig$Configurator` cannot be found. Please ensure the proper classloader has access to all the necessary classes to run your application.

Comment: I edited question please help me out with snippet if you can help @Justin

Comment: What is `com.spring.jms.sockJS.App`? If that's your code, can you share it?

Comment: Its actually `main()` method from where I'm calling the function. I edited the question, you may look into it

Comment: Which line exactly is #44?

Comment: Issue was while connecting to `stompClient.connect(socketURL,sessionHandler).get();` I also added comments where the error actually occurred. I resolved the issue by replacing   `transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new JettyWebSocketClient()));` to          `transports.add(new RestTemplateXhrTransport());`.